# How to reset object's origin

Tags: objects

The origin of my object is not where I want it, so when I set other objects to the parent, they link to the origin rather then the object where I want them. How do I change the origin?

Answer (score 2):

You can recenter the active object's  *[origin](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects#Object_Centers)* (orange dot) by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*> Origin to geometry*, or the button in *3D view > Tool shelf > Tools > Edit > Set origin*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for responding! However, when I tried that, my object still remained below and to the right of the origin. I just settled on setting the origin to the center of mass.

Comment: @Avery That's odd.. Sounds like there might be a stray vert off somewhere or something..